# AWS HTTP API with Python Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/) article describes how to create an HTTP API that calls a Lambda under a node runtime.

I just tried doing the same with a Python lambda with the following handler:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
    };
```

When tested within the Lambda editor, this Lambda returns the exact same as the node Lambda from the article, namely

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}
```

However, the node function works when attached to an HTTP API and navigated to in the browser, while the Python one gives a

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest checking out Cloudwatch logs for details.

It may from your return string. Let's give it a try.

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps('Cheers from AWS Lambda!!')
    }
```

Comment: Haha I can't believe I should have just tried the default template. Well thanks very much and I'll look at the logs if I have more problems